# Rails prefill "add new" form with information

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a Content model and a Stage model. When a users adds new Content, they currently have to select which stage it's associated with in the form:

I'm trying to do two things:

1) Get a list of Stages available

2) Automatically pre-fill the Stage with the one I'm clicking from, similar to this:

```
<%= link_to "+ New", new_content_path(stage: stage.name) %>
```

**After the user submits the Content, it needs to associate the Content with the Stage selected automatically.**

Comment: How content and stage are associated?

Comment: Stage has_many :contents && 
Contents belongs_to :stage

Comment: You can do `new_content_path(stage_name: stage.name)` and access it in the controller/view as `params[:stage_name]`

Answer (score 0):

You can append extra parameters with the URL like you do in a typical GET request: http://example.com?user=all&order=asc

In rails, you can do so with the following line of code:

```
 <%= link_to "Click Me", new_content_path(param1: "value1", param2: "value2") %>
```

Comment: I have Stages as objects, so I need to map this to the SELECT box.

Comment: Please edit your question, and explain there what exactly you want to achieve?